# UWP show text wrapping indications in a TextBlock

Tags: xaml, uwp, textblock

I have a `TextBlock` in my XAML page. The text that goes into that `TextBlock` is dynamic and can be any number of characters. Initially I keep `TextWrapping = Wrap`. But when I click on the `TextBlock`, I switch `TextWrapping` to `NoWrap` by using the `Tapped` event on the `TextBlock` and clicking it again switches it back to `Wrap`. So essentially `Tapped` event on the `TextBlock` toggles between Wrap and NoWrap. This allows me to expand the `TextBlock` to read the whole text in it.

This is all good. Now what I am trying to do is to show some indication inside the `TextBlock` that tells whether some text inside the `TextBlock` is getting wrapped so that the user can click on the `TextBlock` and expand it to  read the whole thing. The indication I wanted to show was something like 3 dots at the end of the `TextBlock` if the text is getting wrapped.
For example if the text inside the `TextBox` is

> Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur, adipisci velit"

but because `TextWrapping = Wrap`, it is getting wrapped after the word 'est' , then I want the content of the `TextBlock` to be something like this:

> Neque porro quisquam est...

(notice the 3 dots after the word est)

How do I achieve this? ( if possible ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are simply looking for the [`TextTrimming`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.texttrimming) property of the `TextBlock`.

Pick either `CharacterEllipsis` or `WordEllipsis` to suit you need.